# No response from TcpListener AcceptTcpClient method

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am using the following code to connect to a port on server (which in this case is my local machine):

```
 int port = 7778;
 IPAddress ipAddress = Dns.Resolve("localhost").AddressList[0];
 var ip1 = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.30.51");
 TcpListener server = new TcpListener(ip1, port);

TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
```

But the code gets stuck at the last line. I don't get any response forever. Is this the problem of port i am using? How can i resolve this issue? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a client that is attempting to connect? what happens with the client? have you tried looking at the windows firewall settings for tcp : 7778 ? have you tried running the server as admin to see if it behaves differently? (note: this is purely as an investigation step; it isn't a "fix" -  just a  way of  identifying potential problem spots); is that IP address one that is actually bound to the machine / device?

Comment: Actually, this code is running in my windows service on my local machine. I am running the server as admin only. I will check firewall settings for that port.

Comment: `AcceptTcpClient()` waits for a **client to connect**. You're talking about _"to connect to a port on server"_. How are you connecting to your listener?

Comment: @CodeCaster : My bad, but where is client connected to when AcceptTcpClient() is called? Isn't it an IP endpoint? You can still give an answer if you understood what I am trying to do? And you have permission to edit too if you think something wrong is written. I will be really thankful.

Comment: When `AcceptTcpClient()` connects nowhere! - The `TcpClient`-Class is used to connect to a `TcpListener`, which you configured. So you need a Client which connects to your server.

Answer (score 4):

`server.AcceptTcpClient()` blocks until a client connects. So, if you're actually connecting, what happens at the client side? Does it establish your connection?
Maybe, there is an error on the client-side, maybe caused by a firewall or something.

The `AcceptTcpClient`-method returns right after the connection has been established. So when it blocks there, it says that there was no connection established.

Keep in mind that in your implementation, only connections via `192.168.30.51` are accepted. Use IPAddress.Any if its irrelevant on what network-interface the connection is incoming.
The `IPAddress` you pass to the TcpListener is the address of the interface which accepts the connection. Please read the [MSDN on TcpListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) carefully. It is not the source address of your client!

Comment: Actually, my guess is that the connection itself is not established. I am not able to find what is blocking my connection. How do i check if firewall is blocking, and how do i resolve that? And, IP Address is hard coded in my example; it comes dynamically.

Comment: Please see my recent edit (last section). May you show us the client-code? Concerning the firewall I'm not able to say anything since I 1) don't know which firewall you are using and 2) have no idea about firewalls at all.

Comment: For the testing purpose, i have just written the above code in an console application under `void main()`. I am running that application on my local machine whose ip is what i have hard coded. And, i am using windows firewall, and i have no idea about firewalls too.

Comment: Try `IPAddress.Any`. On your local machine probably "127.0.0.1" is used.

Comment: Tried with that too. Doesn't work either. It seems there is really an issue with the port. I wrote `server.Pending()` to check, it returns false.

Comment: Did you try another port?

Comment: Again, please show your Client-side code. I doubt there is a problem on the server-side, since it looks pretty ok.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `server.Start()` before `server.AcceptTcpClient()` !